# Active anchor tag changes on scroll using a id and a name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As stated in the title, I am having issues trying to figure out how to get this to work.  I know there are several examples of this out there, but they do not apply to what I am doing or the code I have.

I'm pretty deep into this project and cannot really start over, I have most of it accomplished already but cannot get anything to work for when a user scrolls on the page and the anchor tag in the menu changes with it.

Is there a simple solution using the latest jquery and javascript that will coincide with  and ?

Or am I going to have to literally start over on this project?

Here is a bit of code on what I have:

```
<nav id="menu" class="menu">
                <a class="menu-trigger"></a>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#">:: Join Community ::</a></li>
                <li><a href="#home_wrapper" class="active">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about_wrapper">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#advertise_wrapper">Advertise</a></li>
                <li><a href="#central_wrapper">GP Central</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact_wrapper">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#career_wrapper">Career</a></li>
                <li><a href="#press_wrapper">Press</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">:: My Dashboard ::</a></li>
            </ul>
            </nav>


<div id="main_body">

            <div id="about_wrapper">
            </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>

            <div id="advertise_wrapper">
            </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>

            <div id="central_wrapper">
            </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>

            <div id="contact_wrapper">
            </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>

            <div id="career_wrapper">
            </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>

            <div id="press_wrapper">
            </div>

        </div>
```

I've tried this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
var windscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
$('.page').each(function(i) {
    var posTop = $(this).position().top, 
        h = $(this).height();

    if (posTop  <= windscroll && posTop + h > windscroll ) {
        $('.menu ul li').removeClass('active');
        $('.menu ul li').eq(i).addClass('active');
    }
});
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you make a fiddle please?

Comment: What's `.page` here?

Comment: *Is there a simple solution using the latest jquery and javascript..* : Yes. It is called ScrollSpy: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

Comment: http://cssdeck.com/labs/setting-active-states-on-sticky-navigations-while-scrolling/

Comment: Thank you 4dgaurav - that link helped!  Had to do a few modifications but not near as much if I would have with others!

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer finally with the help of 4dgaurav!

```
var sections = $('div')
  , nav = $('.menu')
  , nav_height = nav.outerHeight();

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
  var cur_pos = $(this).scrollTop();

  sections.each(function() {
    var top = $(this).offset().top - nav_height,
        bottom = top + $(this).outerHeight();

    if (cur_pos >= top && cur_pos <= bottom) {
      nav.find('a').removeClass('active');
      sections.removeClass('active');

      $(this).addClass('active');
      nav.find('a[href="#'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').addClass('active');
    }
  });
});

nav.find('a').on('click', function () {
  var $el = $(this)
    , id = $el.attr('href');

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(id).offset().top - nav_height
  }, 500);

  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var windscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        $('ul li a').each(function(i) {
            var posTop = $($(this).attr('href')).position().top, 
                h = $($(this).attr('href')).height();

            if (posTop  <= windscroll && posTop + h > windscroll ) {
                $('.menu ul li a').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Note: Apply your **CSS** correctly.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/03jg5sxh/)**